# how to open a new window from code behind it is blocked by the browser is there any other way to open

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i am using window.open to open a page in new window but this is blocked by the browser and it is asking the user to allow the popup is there any other way to open a new window which will be used by the other website which will not be blocked by the browser

my code

```
  string url = "../Printticket.aspx";
    string fullURL = "window.open('" + url + "', '_blank', 'height=600,width=1000,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,titlebar=no' );";
       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", fullURL, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Browser blocks popup because you open new window using JavaScript just like most spam websites do.

Instead of using JavaScript you could return simple page with link what opens ticket in new window. It won't be blocked as the user intentionally clicked on the link.

```
<html>
...
   <div>
      Thank you for your purchase. You can print your ticket <a href='www.example.com/Printticket.aspx' target='_blank'>here</a>
   </div>
...
</html>
```

Comment: Opening popups without user action is considered dangerous by most browsers as it is so much abused by different spam sites. That said, you can't be 100% sure that it will work in every browser and you need to provide fallback anyway. I propose to use your existing script to open popup but at the same time display link for users as this is the only safe way to get your user to the ticket.